# Installing Keras - ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree

Tags: python, keras, pip, pypi

I'm trying to install keras on Windows with Python 3.12.1 and am unable to do so due to the error in th title. The full error is below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Nate\PycharmProjects\first_flask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, i
n <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Nate\PycharmProjects\first_flask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, i
n main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Nate\PycharmProjects\first_flask\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, i
n build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 404, in build_wheel 
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 389, in _build_with_
temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup   
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup   
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup  
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_com
mands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_com
mands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command       
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_com
mand
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_comm
and
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command       
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_com
mand
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, i
n run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_comm
and
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command       
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hjzyqeky\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_com
mand
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 72, in run
        File "<string>", line 110, in build_extension
        File "C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '-j16', '--config', 'Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree
Failed to build dm-tree
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dm-tree, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

In my enviroment variables PATH I have the C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312 directory but am wondering if I should also have the C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts directory. Not sure if that's a potential cause of this error. Any help getting the install to work is appreciated. ALso, I'd prefer not to have to install a different python version is possible as I've seen others suggest installing python 3.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras 3 is compatible with Linux and MacOS systems. It is not compatible with Windows. To use it on windows, use WSL2 to run Keras.

Also note that keras 3 currently supports python 3.9 - 3.11.

See https://pypi.org/project/keras/#description for more information.